# Which will have more Performance in DB2

Tags: db2

I need to insert a table from a master table having 2 billion records . Insert needs to satisfy some conditons and also in the some columns to be calculated and then it has to be inserted.

I am having 2 options but  I dont know which to follow to improve performance.

1 option

Create a cursor by filtering from master table with the conditons. and get one by one record for caluclation and then last insertion to the child table

2 option
insert first using into conditon and then calculation using update statement.

Please Assist.

Answer (score 1):

Having a cursor to get data, perform calculation, and then insert into the database will be time consuming. My guess is that since it involves data connections and I/O for each retrieval and insertion (for both the databases )

Databases are usually better with bulk operations, so it will definitely give you better performance if you use Option 2. Option 2 is better for troubleshooting also ( as the process is cleanly separated - step1: download, step2: calculate) than Option 1 where in case of an error in the middle of the process, you'll be forced to redo all the steps again.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a cursor and inserting records one by one might have serious performance issues at the volumes on the order of a Billion . Especially if you have a weak network between your Database tier and App tier . The fastest way to do this could be to use Db2 export utility to download data , let the program manipulate the data from the file and later load the file back to the child table . Apart from the file based option you can also consider the following approaches

1) Write an SQL stored procedure (No need to ship the data out of the database to make changes ) 
2) If you using Java/JDBC use Batch Update feature to update multiple records at the same time 
3) If you using a tool like Informatica, turn on the bulk load feature in informatica

Also see the IBM DW article on imporving insert performance . The article is a little bit older but concepts are still valid . http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/tips/dm-0403wilkins/